# expression stored in variable as string

Tags: javascript, variables, expression

I have this code that works.

```
myDate = str.match(/(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g);
```

However I would like to store the expression as a variable and use that instead.
Something like this:

```
pattern = "/(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g"; // I understand this is wrong somehow

myDate = str.match(pattern);
```

How do I store my expression as a variable and use it the way I have shown?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things in JavaScript, a Regular Expression pattern is an object - specifically, a RegExp object. As [explained in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> There are two ways to create a RegExp object: a literal notation and a constructor.
>
> - The literal notation's parameters are enclosed between slashes and do not use quotation marks.
> - The constructor function's parameters are not enclosed between slashes but do use quotation marks.

The additional point relevant to your example is that the `g` flag is added on the end of the literal notation, but as a separate parameter in the constructor function. So either of the following will work:

```
pattern = /(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g;
pattern = new RegExp('\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})', 'g');
```

The reason your attempt didn't give an error, but didn't match the string is explained [on the MDN page for the `match` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If regexp is a non-RegExp object, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(regexp).

So your code was equivalent to this:

```
pattern = "/(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g";
myDate = str.match(new RegExp(pattern));
```

When what you wanted was this:

```
pattern = "(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})";
myDate = str.match(new RegExp(pattern, "g"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotations:

```js
pattern = /(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g;

myDate = "01-01-2021".match(pattern);

console.log(myDate);
```

Comment: lol, literally got this at same time :D thanks for quick repsonse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after playing about I got it to work by taking the qoutation marks away by doing this.

```
var pattern=/(\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g;
myDate = str.match(pattern);
```